# Как подписать каждое отдельное значение в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив из 25 рандомно созданных параметров (возраст).
При выводе на консоль они выводятся одной строкой:
Age of player: [18, 24, 31, 25, 36, 28, 25, 33, 20, 36, 25, 34, 19, 18, 27, 27, 22, 23, 38, 32, 38, 25, 38, 39, 38]

Как сделать так, чтобы каждый параметр имел свою отдельную подпись?

Например: Age of player #1 is 18, Age of player #2 is 24, Age of player #3 is 31, ...

Существующий код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HomeWork10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfPlayers = 25;
        int playersAgeMin = 18;
        int playersAgeMax = 40;
        int[] team1PlayersAge = new int[numOfPlayers];
           
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
           team1PlayersAge[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (playersAgeMax-playersAgeMin + 1)) + playersAgeMin;
        }
        System.out.println("Age of player " + Arrays.toString(team1PlayersAge));
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто напечатать значение `i`-го элемента внутри цикла: `for (...) { ...; System.out.println("Age of player #" + (i + 1) + ": " + team1PlayersAge[i]); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо надо непосредственно под строкой `team1PlayersAge[i] = ...` прямо внутри цикла и писать

```
System.out.println("Age of player #" +  i + " is "  + team1PlayersAge[i]);
```

а **НЕ вне** цикла

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` в Java возвращает строковое представление **всего** массива, так что тогда верный код будет `System.out.println("Age of player #" +  i + " is " + team1PlayersAge[i]);`

Comment: Да, точно,.... .